# Can i add effects to realtime audio stream in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, audio, signal-processing, web-audio-api

I have an audio stream , at the moment from ffmpeg , which id like to add real-time effects to .

Is this possible with Javascript.

My file management code is all in JS (nodejs) and I don't need any interaction with frontend code.

Can i use web-audio in the backend (eg howler) .... I'm thinking not.

I've thought of using Python , ie import audio to numpy array , process and then stream the result , or save to file and stream the file (i dont want to stream pcm so need to convert to mp3 when streaming out)
- A problem i've been having here (trying to use PYO) is that the software is to be hosted in cloud , so i have no access to a sound card , which PYO seems to require.

- Another possibility is something like audiolazy to add dsp.

Any thoughts or advise would be gratefully received.
Thanks

Answer (score -2):

The [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API) gives you many options. You can create an [`Audio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement) instance, give it an [`AudioContext`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext), and apply a multitude of [`AudioNode`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioNode) to it to apply varying effects. There is significant documentation on [Using The Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Using_Web_Audio_API).

Comment: Web Audio seems great , but to do what i want i'd have to fake browser calls to a running process in order to change the effects on some audio.
I'll look into it further . At the moment i'm heading in a python direction , but it would be nice to do it in javascript.
Thanks for the reply,

Comment: Actually you can pass the audio through multiple `AudioNode`s to obtain nearly any effect, it just kind of depends on what it is you're trying to do. Round tripping back to the server is probably not necessary.

Comment: This all needs an actual browser running, which is not what OP wanted. You cannot use the web audio api without a browser.

Comment: @Eindbaas - You bring up a valid point I missed from the original post: that he's doing this in Node. So the question then becomes, what problem is it the @Russ_ell is trying to solve? If he's applying live effects to the stream, where is the stream going and how? And technically it is possible to utilize the Web Audio API via node, using third party libraries like [web-audio-api](https://github.com/audiojs/web-audio-api), you just have to figure out what the `audioContext.destination` is supposed to be.

Comment: @Steve -Cutter -Blades - I am trying to run two constant audio streams (selecting files one after another in real time) adding time variant effects on each stream (dependent on the start/end times of individual files on either stream) . Real time mixing if you like . e.g. 5 seconds before the end of a file on stream 1 stream 2 gets a bit of reverb. It'd be nice to do it with JavaScript as the whole stack uses it , but at the moment I'm going down the route of spawning a python script from Node that deals with the audio processing side of things.

Comment: The mixed stream would eventually be sent to icecast.